# shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_train3.values, feature_names= X_train3.columns) giving an error after applying data preprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, shap

```py
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\R_Data41.csv")
df.head()
feature_names =  ['Al', 'Co', 'Cr', 'Fe', 'Ni', 'Cu', 'Mn', 'Ti', 'V', 'Nb', 'Mo', 'Zr','Hf', 'Ta', 'W', 'C', 'Mg', 'Zn', 'Si', 'Re', 'N', 'Sc', 'Li', 'Sn','Be', 'Num_of_Elem', 'Density_calc', 'dHmix', 'dSmix', 'dGmix', 'Tmelt', 'n_Para', 'Atom_Size_Diff', 'Elect.Diff', 'VEC']

df['Phases'].value_counts()
```

```py
Im              463,
BCC_SS          441,
FCC_SS          354,
FCC_PLUS_BCC    102, 
Name: Phases, dtype: int64
```

```py
X= pd.DataFrame(df, columns=feature_names)

y=df['Phases']

print(X.shape)  # (1360, 35)

print(y.shape)  # (1360,)
```

There are 6 missing values in the dataframe, which has been imputed using KNN Imputer.

```py
imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=5)

imputer.fit(X_train)

X_train1= imputer.transform(X_train)

X_test1= imputer.transform(X_test)
```

After that standard scaling is performed.

```py
scaler= StandardScaler()

X_train2= scaler.fit_transform(X_train1)

X_test2= scaler.transform(X_test1)
```

PCA decomposition is performed in the next step.

```py
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca= PCA(n_components= 0.98)

X_train3= pca.fit_transform(X_train2)

X_test3 =pca.transform(X_test2)
```

XGBoost classifier is then used to classify these 4 classes.

```py
XGB = XGBClassifier()

XGB.fit(X_train3, y_train)

XGB_pred= XGB.predict(X_test3)

XGB_pred_proba= XGB.predict_proba(X_test3)

XGB_ROC= roc_auc_score(y_test, XGB_pred_proba, multi_class='ovo')


from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

print(classification_report(y_test, XGB_pred))
```

```py
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.83      0.82      0.82        93
           1       0.88      0.95      0.91        88
           2       0.92      0.86      0.89        71
           3       0.83      0.75      0.79        20

    accuracy                           0.87       272
   macro avg       0.86      0.85      0.85       272
weighted avg       0.87      0.87      0.87       272
```

SHAP VALUE-

```py
import shap

explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(XGB)

shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_train3)

shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_train3.values, feature_names= X_train3.columns)
```

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'

Getting this error. Can anyone please help me know, how to evaluate shap values, it's forceplot and waterfall plot.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the line

```
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_train3.values, feature_names= X_train3.columns)
```

To

```
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_train3, feature_names= X_train3.columns)
```

This is because X_train3 is already in the format of a numpy array and does not require calling of `.values`